# reset dropdown based on checkbox click and unclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a drop down with the following structure

```html
<select class="load_instrument" id="review_select" onchange="changeReviewField(this)">
  <option value="data2" data-type="child" style="display: block;">a2</option>
  <option value="data3" data-type="child" style="display: block;">b1</option>
  <option value="data4" data-type="child" style="display: block;">b2</option>
  <option value="calculation1" data-type="child" style="display: block;">al_diff_a</option>
  <option value="calculation9" data-type="child" style="display: block;">c_dev_a</option>
  <option value="calculation7" data-type="child" style="display: block;">disp_a</option>
  <option value="calculation14" data-type="child" style="display: block;">bearing</option>
  <option value="calculation13" data-type="child" style="display: block;">res</option>
  <option value="calculation2" data-type="child" style="display: block;">al_diff_b</option>
  <option value="calculation10" data-type="child" style="display: block;">c_dev_b</option>
  <option value="calculation6" data-type="child" style="display: block;">dev_b</option>
  <option value="calculation11" data-type="child" style="display: block;">cd_a</option>
  <option value="calculation12" data-type="child" style="display: block;">cd_b</option>
  <option value="calculation4" data-type="child" style="display: block;">al_sum_b</option>
  <option value="calculation8" data-type="child" style="display: block;">disp_b</option>
  <option value="calculation3" data-type="child" style="display: block;">al_sum_a</option>
  <option value="calculation5" data-type="child" style="display: block;">dev_a</option>
  <option value="m.calculation4" data-type="master" style="display: none;">c_dev_a</option>
  <option value="m.calculation5" data-type="master" style="display: none;">c_dev_b</option>
  <option value="m.calculation6" data-type="master" style="display: none;">cd_a</option>
  <option value="elapsed_time" data-type="master" style="display: none;">Elapsed Time</option>
</select>
```

and have a checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="master_fields" id="master_fields" style="vertical-align: -6px;" >
```

```js
$("#master_fields").on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
    $("#review_select option[data-type='master']").show();
    $("#review_select option[data-type='child']").hide();
  } else {
    $("#review_select option[data-type='master']").hide();
    $("#review_select option[data-type='child']").show();
  }
});
```

when checking it type master elements are shown in dropdown and child types will be hidden, when unchecking master elements will be hidden and child will be shown, the issue is that  the first element of child option is always visible, it is not getting hidden, anybody please help

Comment: Just edited the post. You do have a checkbox but no one could see it earlier because of the incorrect formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a2 is selected by default in the dropdown even if you are hiding it.
You can put `selected` attribute for the option you want to be visible initially.

`<option selected data-type="child">a2</option>`

in your code

```
$("#master_fields").on('click', function() {
if ($(this).prop("checked") == true) {
        console.log($("option[data-type='master']").length);
    $("option[data-type='master']").show();
    $('#review_select').prop('selectedIndex',$("option[data-type='child']").length);
    $("#review_select option[data-type='child']").hide();
} else {
    $("#review_select option[data-type='master']").hide();
   $('#review_select').prop('selectedIndex',0);
    $("#review_select option[data-type='child']").show();
}
})
```

I have edited the code as per the requirements, 
use `$("option[data-type='child']").length`, to find the number of options with child

Comment: issue is if i choose any option and checking or unchecking checkbox the selected value is not going

Comment: @CARLOINA just check if this is working for you, I have updated the code.

Comment: cannot hard  code like 17,because i options are coming from php code, am only shown html here to make understand,so how it work

Comment: @CARLOINA okay, use  `$("option[data-type='child']").length` instead of 17.

Comment: @McRist I see the problem now

Comment: @McRist Thank You so much its resetting , on check and uncheck any option to make first value get selected too ?

Comment: @McRist THANK YOU SO MUCH ITS WORKING AWESOME, I DONT HAVE MUCH REPUTATION TO MARK  POINT FOR YOU,PLEASE ALL GIVE HIM GOOD SCORE

Comment: @CARLOINA the answer doesn't recored the previous key it always return to the first child when the checkbox in unchecked.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine simply import jQuery with a jQuery CDN. Hence, simply paste this at the top of your code

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
  crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

Also be sure to actually insert the checkbox

```
<input id='master_fields' type='checkbox'>
```

I have attached the working example. Hope it helped :)

```js
let prev_item = 0
$("#master_fields").on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).prop("checked") === true) {
    $("#review_select option[data-type='child']").hide();
    $("#review_select option[data-type='master']").show();
    prev_item = $('#review_select').prop('selectedIndex')
    $('#review_select').prop('selectedIndex', $("option[data-type='child']").length)
  } else {
    $("#review_select option[data-type='master']").hide();
    $("#review_select option[data-type='child']").show();
    $('#review_select').prop('selectedIndex', prev_item);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

<select class="load_instrument" id="review_select">
  <option value="data2" data-type="child" style="display: block;">a2</option>
  <option value="data3" data-type="child" style="display: block;">b1</option>
  <option value="data4" data-type="child" style="display: block;">b2</option>
  <option value="calculation1" data-type="child" style="display: block;">al_diff_a</option>
  <option value="calculation9" data-type="child" style="display: block;">c_dev_a</option>
  <option value="calculation7" data-type="child" style="display: block;">disp_a</option>
  <option value="calculation14" data-type="child" style="display: block;">bearing</option>
  <option value="calculation13" data-type="child" style="display: block;">res</option>
  <option value="calculation2" data-type="child" style="display: block;">al_diff_b</option>
  <option value="calculation10" data-type="child" style="display: block;">c_dev_b</option>
  <option value="calculation6" data-type="child" style="display: block;">dev_b</option>
  <option value="calculation11" data-type="child" style="display: block;">cd_a</option>
  <option value="calculation12" data-type="child" style="display: block;">cd_b</option>
  <option value="calculation4" data-type="child" style="display: block;">al_sum_b</option>
  <option value="calculation8" data-type="child" style="display: block;">disp_b</option>
  <option value="calculation3" data-type="child" style="display: block;">al_sum_a</option>
  <option value="calculation5" data-type="child" style="display: block;">dev_a</option>
  <option value="m.calculation4" data-type="master" style="display: none;">c_dev_a</option>
  <option value="m.calculation5" data-type="master" style="display: none;">c_dev_b</option>
  <option value="m.calculation6" data-type="master" style="display: none;">cd_a</option>
  <option value="elapsed_time" data-type="master" style="display: none;">Elapsed Time</option>
</select>
<input id='master_fields' type='checkbox'>
```

Comment: please run it it wont work,the selected option is not going in check and uncheck

Comment: Oh ok I understand your problem now, I'll put up an edit.